# Mac not going to sleep after iTunes stops playing

Tags: macos, itunes, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

### Hardware/Software

- MacBook Pro 17" 2009
- Lion 10.7.3
- iTunes 10.6

### Issue

Unlike a lot of posts on the internet, my Mac actually goes to sleep just fine, usually.

However, if iTunes was playing something, and then I either explicitly stop it playing, or the movie/track/playlist comes to an end, it runs down the battery to zero!

I understand that iTunes doesn't let the Mac go to sleep if it's playing something, but if I explicitly press the stop/pause button, or the media stops playing, shouldn't the Mac go to sleep as per usual?

Anyway I can diagnose/fix this? is it a known issue?

cheers!

Comment: I made a program that can help you with this (slightly). This thread is 4 years old, so I'll hesitate before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Check if really iTunes is causing this by opening a terminal and entering:

```
 pmset -g
```

If sleep is prevented by a process its ID is listed, like here:

```
 ...
 sleep      0 (imposed by 129)
 ...
```

Then check which process blocks going to sleep, in this example:

```
 ps -A | grep 129

   129 ??        37:39.06 /usr/sbin/coreaudiod
```

Then try killing (quitting) the process and check if you can send your computer to sleep, and if iTunes is still working. In this example it would be:

```
 sudo kill -3 129
```

---

Otherwise you could try re-installing iTunes, and/or repairing your file-premissions in Disk-Utility.